# Why is my data load split between 2 different instances?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, bulk-load

I am loading data via python from SQL to MariaDB and my python script runs fine, it import the data and loads all of it. When I check the table to see how much data is there by doing `SELECT COUNT(*)` FROM TABLE then it shows only 120,000 records. When I open a new SQL script in DBeaver, and run the same command, it shows the table only has 80,000 records.

It’s the same table, same database, same everything. I think the issue is when I made a copy of the connection in DBeaver. I made a copy of the connection I am currently on then I deleted it when I was done using it so now I am only working with one copy of the database and the connection to MariaDB itself. Since then, it’s like splitting the load and I don’t know why. I deleted one copy, is there somewhere else I need to delete it?

It’s so stupid, I do right click database -> SQL editor -> New SQL script then I enter `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE` and it returns 120,000 record.

Then I do right click database -> SQL editor -> New SQL script then I enter `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE` and it returns 80,000 records in a new SQL script window. I have no idea what the issue is, there is only 1 table and 1 database in my whole DBeaver.

Comment: Different server maybe?

Comment: SQL Server is nothing to do with MariaDB... please correct your tags.

Comment: You perform the exact same steps in Dbeaver? You connect to the same database server and open a sql editor and submit the exact same sql, and you get different results? That doesn't sound like a thing that could happen. Is there more than one MariaDB server behind a load balancer, and you are pointing at the load balancer when you connect (a totally nonsensical setup, but the only thing I can imagine that would cause such a thing).

Comment: Just for the record *" I think the issue is when I made a copy of the connection in DBeaver. I made a copy of the connection I am currently on then I deleted it when I was done using it so now I am only working with one copy of the database and the connection to MariaDB itself."* <-- This is not causing the issue. Dbeaver is merely a client and the connection is merely metadata telling dbeaver how to connect to the server. It has nothing to do with the data, table, or server. If you have TWO mariadb servers and you are toggling between them in your connection settings, that's another story.

Comment: The MariaDB database is run on a cluster. I don’t know what to do about that or specify for it to run on just the one cluster??

Answer (score 0):

This is a probably transaction-commit issue. In your python program be sure to to call [.commit()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html) every few thousand records while you're loading, and also at the end of your program before you close the connection to your MariaDB server.

```py
cnx.commit()
```